# how remove 'a' tag in a string by its class name

Tags: php, preg-match

i'am trying to remove a tag by class name class="btn" 
from below $str variable using php code

```
$str = '<div class="btn-holder">
<a class="btn" href="=#">
<span>Log In</span>
</a>
<p><strong>
<em>
<a id="reset" href="#">Reset My Password</a>
</em>
</strong>
</p>
</div>';
```

Comment: $str = '<div class="btn-holder">
<a class="btn" href="=#">
<span>Log In</span>
</a>
<p><strong>
<em>
<a id="reset" href="#">Reset My Password</a>
</em>
</strong>
</p>
</div>';

Comment: @YasirPoongadan hahaha no dude. He's asking for anything you have tried to achieve that. You have tried, right?

Comment: `#\<a class='btn'\>(.+?)\<\/a\>#s`?

Comment: $str = str_replace('<a class="btn" href="#">
<span>Log In</span>
</a>', '<input type="submit" value="login">' , $str);

Comment: I'd suggest either a DOM parser or using JavaScript / jQuery where you can easily remove links by class with proper selectors. Regex and strreplace are likely to not work when you have a white space different or quotes or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Try, this one:

```
$str = '<div class="btn-holder">
<a class="btn" href="=#">
<span>Log In</span>
</a>
<p><strong>
<em>
<a id="reset" href="#">Reset My Password</a>
</em>
</strong>
</p>
</div>';
$result = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: $result = preg_replace('/<a class="btn" href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $str);

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('#<a.*?class="btn".*?>.*?</a>#', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$str = '...';`

echo preg_replace('/<(\w)+.*?class=["\']btn["\'].*?>(.*?)</\1>/s', '', $str);

This RegExp removes all elements with class "btn" from $str.

If you want to preserve the tag content, use `\\2` on `preg_replace`.

`echo preg_replace('/<(\w)+.*?class=["\']btn["\'].*?>(.*?)</\1>/s', '\\2', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

Dont' use regexp to parse XML documents. There are other ways to do it. Eg:

```
$doc = new DOMDOcument;
$doc->loadxml('your XML');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query('//s[contains(@class,"btn")]') as $node) {
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $doc->savexml();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, better way is use a jquery library.

```
$('a.btn').remove();
```

Comment: jQuery is client-side so it's useless for server-side scripting.